# How to remove backup logs on application startup

Tags: python, logging

I have a `RotatingFileHandler` with `mode=w`, `maxBytes=20000000` and `backupCount=10` as shown below:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=file


[formatters]
keys=simple

[formatter_simple]
format=[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s : %(name)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%s

[handlers]
keys=file

[handler_file]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=(log_directory,'w', 20000000, 10)
```

This means that after a period of time, 11 distinct log files will be present ( `test.log, test.log.1, ..., test.log.10` ). My requirement is when the application is started, I want to delete all of the backup log files (`test.log.1, ..., test.log.10`). The content of `test.log` (current) log file will be removed anyway because `mode` is set to `w`.

Answer (score 0):

That task is not under logging scope, you should "manually" delete them upon application start. Use `os` or `shutil`.